# JSON.parse() not working on jQuery data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get a JSON file via jQuery `$.getJSON(url, function(data) {` ...
and want to parse it with either

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

or

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

The first line gives me "syntax error" (using IE8, should support `JSON.parse`), the second gives me "'center' is null or not an object".

This is the valid JSON file I'm using:

```
{
"center":{"lat":"51.99637","lon":"13.07520"},
"locations":
[
    { "name":"a string","info":"another string" },
    ... some more here ...
]
}
```

I'm not too familiar with Javascript. What am I doing wrong?

If I use a simple JSON array (= just the content of locations) I get valid data with `$.each`.
Do I have to do something with data before I can use JSON.parse on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the function is slightly misleading : it doesn't give you `JSON` but already a parsed object. What it does is fetch some `JSON` and parse it for you.

`data` is a plain javascript object, you don't need to parse it.

Comment: Should probably be `JSON.parseFromString`

Comment: I'd suggest to rename the function as `$.fetchSomeJSONAndParseItForMePlease = $.getJSON;`

Comment: Considering how angry people seem to get when someone calls a JavaScript object "JSON," you'd think more people would be up in arms about changing the jQuery method name to `$.getJavaScriptDataStructure`

Comment: Yeah, let's make a manifesto web site `stop-confusing-people-about-what-is-json-with-your-stupid-function-name.org` !

Comment: Ah, cool, works. Thanks for this quick answer! Should have been obvious to me. Sorry for not thinking.

Answer (score 2):

$.getJSON will parse the data for you - you don't need to parse it manually after the fact.